# Making ArrayList Size equal to other Array Lists Available in Java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, match, addition

I have 2 ArrayLists of varying sizes. Example -
Array1.size() = 10
Array2.size() = 5
I want at all times these arrays to have same size. Thus, I have another class to ensure this. But obviously, it isn't working for me. Please help!
Below is that Class code -

```
for (int i = Array2.size(); i == Array1.size(); i++) {
       Array2.add(i, "Test");
}
```

The above loop for just doesn't add 'Test' to the Array2 so it matches the size of Array1. Any ideas guys? Please help!

Comment: Not so sure what you are trying to accomplish with that, but change `==` to `<=`

Comment: If you want to maintain same size why do you need `for` loop; Below code should be sufficient `if(Array1.size() > Array2.size()) {Array2.ensureCapacity(Array1.size());} else {Array1.ensureCapacity(Array2.size())}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i is never equal to Array1.size(), this loop never adds anything

```
for (int i = Array2.size(); i == Array1.size(); i++) {
       Array2.add(i, "Test");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your loop uses the wrong condition.

```
for (int i = Array2.size(); i == Array1.size(); i++) {
       Array2.add(i, "Test");
}
```

This would mean the loop runs while `i == Array1.size()`, which is of course nonsense.

try

```
for (int i = Array2.size(); i < Array1.size(); i++) {
       Array2.add(i, "Test");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for loop is:

> > for (initialization; termination; increment) {
> >         statement(s) } 
> >     When using this version of the for statement, keep in mind that:
>
> - The initialization expression initializes the loop; it's executed once, as the loop begins.
> - When the termination expression evaluates to false, the loop terminates.
> - The increment expression is invoked after each iteration through the loop; it is perfectly acceptable for this expression to increment
>     or decrement a value.

In your case the loop is:

```
for (int i = Array2.size(); i == Array1.size(); i++) {
       Array2.add(i, "Test");
}
```

It starts from `5` `(Arrays2.size())` and checks whether `i==10` which is not true (read false) and so it terminates without doing anything. It does not get into the loop at all.

Comment: @BharatNanwani If this answer helped you please accept it so that it can be beneficial for others too.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow